# Debugging Start Commit Scripts SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to debug an svn start-commit script, but I can't appear to get the value of `USER`.

```
#!/bin/sh
USER="$2"
if [ "$USER" = "test" ]; then exit 0; fi
```

I am using a linux account where

```
echo $USER 
returns test
```

but this start-commit hook never returns 0. When I add an `echo $USER` before

```
if [ "$USER" = "test" ]; then exit 0; fi
```

there is no value returned which confuses me. Is there some magic within linux or svn that I am missing?

I have also tried `echo $USER > &2` to return to stderror
 with no success

Comment: `USER="$2"` in _my_ version of svn (1.7.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see output from Subversion hooks, you need to do two things:

- Output everything you want to see to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT` (the default output of the `echo` command).
- Fail the hook. You need to have something other than an exit of `0`.

Your echo statement needs to be:

```
echo "User = '$USER'" >&2
```

The `>&2` will move the output of `echo` to STDERR.

Then, you'll have to add an `exit 2` to the bottom of your script. You won't be able to commit changes since your hook will always fail, but you'll be able to see the output of your hook script.

I take advantage of this behavior by logging everything I'm doing to STDERR. If the hook works as planned, the user sees nothing. Otherwise, the user gets the logging output which they can send to me to analyze.

You might need to do something like this:

```
USER=$2
if [ $USER = "test" ]
then
    exit_code=2
else
    exit_code=0
fi
[...]
exit $exit_code
```

This way, if user `test` tries something, the hook will fail, and you'll see all `STDERR` output.

Comment: `$USER=2` is not valid syntax. Perhaps you meant `USER=2`? Even so, this is bad form -- use of all-caps names for local variables means you can have namespace conflicts with builtin and environment variables (which, for such a generic name as `USER`, is actually downright likely; PAM is frequently configured to export an environment variable by that name, for instance).

Comment: Yes, it should be `USER` and not `$USER`. This is what happens when you answer both Perl and BASH questions at the same time. I always use lowercase variable names in my script, but in this case, I was just copying the user's script. However, even if the user overwrote an established builtin variable, it will be restored to its old value or purpose after the script runs. This is probably why there are so many shell scripts that have capitalized variable names. Thanks for catching that bug.

Answer (score 2):

[Read the docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html). It says the username is the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, it should have been 2, but the question that I am more interested in is why I can not return any values to the command-line with echo from a start-commit script :)

Answer (score 1):

Output from `stderr` is only returned by Subversion to the caller if the hook fails; it is not transmitted on success.

You're better off logging to a file if you want unconditional logging:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ using /bin/sh turns off bash-specific features; use /bin/bash instead

exec >/tmp/hook-log.$$ 2>&1   # redirects both stdout and stderr to a log file
PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'  # sets the format string used by set -x to include
                              # ...source file and line number in each line of
                              # ...output
set -x                        # tells the shell to log each command it runs,
                              # ...prefixed by the evaluated content of the
                              # ...format string set in PS4
: "$@"                        # show your argument list in set -x output
# ...rest of your hook here.
```

...then, you can find logs from your sessions in files matching `/tmp/hook-log.*`.